# Solving a maze using recursion in java from file

Tags: java, file, recursion, maze

I am trying to solve a maze using recursion but after the edits I made the solved maze never gets outputed in the end and i have no clue why is that so.
I would appreciate if you guys could try and debug this problem because I have no idea where to start from.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class recursionMaze {

    private char[][] Maze;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private int rowStart, colStart;
    private String outputFilename;

    public recursionMaze(String filename) throws IOException {
        try {
            this.outputFilename = filename;
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                sb.append(reader.nextLine());
                this.rows++;
            }
            this.cols = sb.length() / this.rows;
            this.Maze = new char[this.rows][this.cols];
            int m = 0;
            System.out.println();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                    this.Maze[i][j] = sb.charAt(m++);
                }
            }
            reader.close();
            findStart();
            Solve(this.rowStart, this.colStart);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void findStart() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                if (Maze[i][j] == 'S') {
                    this.rowStart = i;
                    this.colStart = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean Solve(int row, int col) {
        char right = col + 1 < this.cols ? this.Maze[row][col + 1] : 'S';
        char down = row + 1 < this.rows ? this.Maze[row + 1][col] : 'S';
        char left = col - 1 >= 0 ? this.Maze[row][col - 1] : 'S';
        char up = row - 1 >= 0 ? this.Maze[row - 1][col] : 'S';

        if (right == 'G' || left == 'G' || up == 'G' || down == 'G') {
            this.Maze[row][col] = '+';

            try {
                File file = new File(this.outputFilename + " solved");

                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
                for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                        writer.print(this.Maze[i][j]);
                    }
                    writer.println();
                }
                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return true;
        }

        boolean solved = false;

        if (this.Maze[row][col] != 'S') {
            this.Maze[row][col] = '+';
        }
        if (right == '.' && !solved) {
            solved = Solve(row, col + 1);
        }
        if (down == '.' && !solved) {
            solved = Solve(row + 1, col);
        }
        if (left == '.' && !solved) {
            solved = Solve(row, col - 1);
        }
        if (up == '.' && !solved) {
            solved = Solve(row - 1, col);
        }
        if (!solved) {
            this.Maze[row][col] = '.';
        }
        return solved;
    }

    public static void main(String agrs[]) throws Exception {
        try {
            new recursionMaze("C:\\Users\\achtc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\Maze Folder\\Maze5.txt");
            System.out.println("File has been outputed.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

I keep getting this whenever I run

```
File has been outputed.
```

This is how the text file looks like

```
S...##
#.#...
#.## #
..#.##
#...#G
#.#...
```

Comment: When you report a stack trace, it also helps if you clearly identify which line in the file this is. Otherwise we have to cut & paste your code and run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is coming as you are trying to access elements of array without adding any check or bound on the index you are accessing.

This happens on these line of code :

```
char right = this.Maze[row][col + 1];
char down = this.Maze[row + 1][col];
char left = this.Maze[row][col - 1];
char up = this.Maze[row - 1][col];
```

No check is there to make sure that col -1 is not negative or row+1 is not exceding actual number of rows etc ..

Try using these LOC instead (Just for example sake, the actual logic would depend upon your problem statement):

```
char right = col+1 < this.cols ? this.Maze[row][col + 1] : 'S';
char down = row+1 < this.rows ? this.Maze[row + 1][col] : 'S';
char left = col-1 >=0 ? this.Maze[row][col - 1] : 'S';
char up =row-1 >=0 ?  this.Maze[row - 1][col]: 'S';



public class RecursionMaze {  

private static char[][] Maze = new char[20][20];
private int rows;
private int cols;
private int rowStart, colStart;
private String outputFilename;

public RecursionMaze(String filename) throws IOException {
    try {
        this.outputFilename = filename;
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            sb.append(reader.nextLine());
            this.rows++;
        }
        this.cols = sb.length() / this.rows;
        this.Maze = new char[this.rows][this.cols];
        int m = 0;
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                this.Maze[i][j] = sb.charAt(m++);
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        findStart();
        Solve(this.rowStart, this.colStart);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void findStart() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            if (Maze[i][j] == 'S') {
                this.rowStart = i;
                this.colStart = j;
            }
        }
    }
}

private boolean Solve(int row, int col) {
    char right = col + 1 < this.cols ? this.Maze[row][col + 1] : 'S';
    char down = row + 1 < this.rows ? this.Maze[row + 1][col] : 'S';
    char left = col - 1 >= 0 ? this.Maze[row][col - 1] : 'S';
    char up = row - 1 >= 0 ? this.Maze[row - 1][col] : 'S';

    if (right == 'G' || left == 'G' || up == 'G' || down == 'G') {
        this.Maze[row][col] = '+';

        try {
            File file = new File(this.outputFilename + " solved");

            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (int i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
                    writer.print(this.Maze[i][j]);
                }
                writer.println();
            }
            writer.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean solved = false;

    if (this.Maze[row][col] != 'S') {
        this.Maze[row][col] = '+';
    }
    if (right == '.' && !solved) {
        solved = Solve(row, col + 1);
    }
    if (down == '.' && !solved) {
        solved = Solve(row + 1, col);
    }
    if (left == '.' && !solved) {
        solved = Solve(row, col - 1);
    }
    if (up == '.' && !solved) {
        solved = Solve(row - 1, col);
    }
    if (!solved) {
        this.Maze[row][col] = '.';
    }
    return solved;

}

public static void main(String agrs[]) throws Exception {
    try {
        new RecursionMaze("/Users/himani.agarwal/Documents/test100/host-service-user/src/main/resources/Maze.txt");
        System.out.println("File has been outputed.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR : " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked to solve the out of bounds issue but now it doesn't print out the maze and the solved maze

Comment: Added full class for more clarity. It is working for me.Output created like S+..##
#+#...
#+## #
.+#.##
#+++#G
#.#+++

Comment: Never mind I am just dumb it works perfectly fine.Thanks for the help